# Trying to run hyperledger byfn build your first network and I run into erro 001

Tags: ubuntu, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am trying to build my first network as per instructions [Building your first network](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html)
but I keep running into this error:

```
Build your first network (BYFN) end-to-end test

Channel name : mychannel
Creating channel...
CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
CORE_PEER_ID=cli
CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
+ peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
+ res=1
+ set +x
2018-05-08 15:51:51.677 UTC [main] main -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto, missing /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp folder
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========
```

Any suggestions would greatly help

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @GariSingh Ubuntu. Version 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Your crypto materials are not getting generated properly as required . 
Check that you have all the **Prerequisites** installed on the platform(s)
I hope you have downloaded all the **platform specific** binaries 
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh

This will make sure you have the correct **Cryptogen** and **Configtxgen** tools for creating crypto material,ca clients and channel configurations .

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of reasons why you will get this error but turns out for me the problem was that I was running byfn.sh already and i could not execute it. I had to do `./byfn.sh -m down` first and then then `./byfn.sh -m up` again to make it execute properly.

Comment: you may also need to kill your docker containers first